# How to write Json/dict into file with pretty print along with single quotes?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pretty-print

I'm new to stack overflow. It's my first question here.
I've data (JSON/dict). I'm writing this to a file by prefixing it's corresponding dictionary name as below:

```
open(file_name,'w') as fh: 
    fh.write("dict_name = " + json.dumps(dict_values,indent=2))
```

This works totally fine, but what with double quotes. I need single quotes instead along with pretty print/some readable format.
I tried `json.dumps(dict_values,indent=2).replace("\"","'")`, but this replaces double quotes with single quotes but it's neither a good idea nor correct way to apply to dictionary. Could you please help me?

Comment: Why do you need single quotes? JSON only uses double quotes.

Comment: See the JSON specification at http://www.json.org/.

Comment: @Barmar: Finally, it would be dictionary. So, as part of PEP 8 need it. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes) says: *In Python, single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings are the same. This PEP does not make a recommendation for this.* Where does it say that you have to use single quotes for a dictionary?

Comment: @Barmar : Ok, got it. But still, is there any way to achieve that in single quotes ? Inner level data may contain multiple key-value pairs with data enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: No it won't. `json.dumps()` encodes all the nested elements, and it will use double quotes for everything.

Comment: You would have to write your own version of `json.dumps`. It will have to enclose all strings in single quotes instead of double quotes, and escape any embedded single quotes. The normal version just escapes double quotes.

Comment: Since this is open source code, there's nothing stopping you from copying it and modifying it to do what you want.

Comment: You should also be aware that JSON objects are rather limited compared to Python dicts. Eg, all keys in JSON _must_ be strings. So if you want to serialise an arbitrary Python dict you should _not_ be using `json.dumps`.